# How do I Count multiple columns with reducebykey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I'm trying to count the total number of each key in two separate columns.

I pull the two columns from cassandra with:

```
val data = sc.cassandraTable("Meter","Measured_Value").where("\"Time_Key\" = 1601822").select("Power","Start_Frequency")
```

from that I've tried mapping the two columns and using reduceByKey but can't seem to get it to map properly.

I think i need to map the following but can't seem to make it work:

```
power:Float => power,1
frequency:Double => frequency,1
```

And then do a `.reduceByKey(_ + _)`

But i'm guessing. Any help with the syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val data: RDD[(Float,Double)] = sc.cassandraTable("Meter","Measured_Value")
           .where("\"Time_Key\" = 1601822")
           .select("Power","Start_Frequency")
           .as((_:Float,_:Double)) 

val reduced: RDD[(Float,Double)] = data.reduceByKey{ case(left, right) => left + right}
```

Comment: I tried your code but get: `<console>:52: error: not found: type RDD
       val data: RDD[(Float,Double)] = sc.cassandraTable("SB1000_47130646","Measured_Value")` @doanduyhai